# Find a graph on eight vertices with a pair of pseudosimilar vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Can somebody give me an example of a graph on eight vertices that has a pair of pseudosimilar vertices? Or, is it not possible? If it is not possible, please do not give me a proof, as I would like to figure out how to prove it myself.

> **Definition**: vertices $u$ and $v$ in a graph $X$ are **similar** if there is an automorphism of $X$ that maps $u$ to $v$. If $u$ and $v$ are similar, then the vertex-deleted subgraphs $X-u$ and $X-v$ are isomorphic. If $X-u$ and $X-v$ are isomorphic but $u$ and $v$ are not similar, we say that they are **pseudosimilar**.

Comment: This is similar to the [reconstruction conjencture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture)

Comment: So far, I haven't found any counter-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a copy of the first figure in Kimble et al.'s "[Pseudosimilar vertices in a graph](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190050207/abstract)", *J. Graph Th.* 5(2) (2006), which as of writing is the top Google hit for "pseudosimilar vertices". The graph has 8 vertices and is stated to be the smallest possible graph having pseudosimilar vertices.

[image]

The paper credits the discovery of this example to Harary and Palmer ("On similar points of a graph", *J. Math. Mech.* 15 (1966); "A note on similar points and similar lines of a graph", *Rev. Roumaine Math. Pures Appl.* 10 (1965)).

Comment: I assume reproducing one figure with attribution falls under fair use.

Comment: It seems like a proper citation to me ;-)

Comment: I was looking for some smaller counterexample. No wonder I didn't succeed.

Comment: Having posted this answer, I have effectively acted as someone's Google daemon. I feel quite ridiculous.

Comment: So you want me to unupvote? ;-)